# Debugging Django

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

This is a newbie question.  I am having difficulty adding a calandar widget into my form using the Dynarch calendar widget.   My example is derived from the from the popup example at: http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/doc/  .

When I click the button, the calendar doesn't show up.  Instead the page refreshes.  I can't tell what is happening here.  I have no idea if this trigger is even getting called correctly.

My server is receiving a post command. No post should be getting called here. I don't want any data to be posted, just the calendar trigger to make the calendar visible.    This should just load the button.

How can I get to the bottom of what is really happening here? Advice?

```
 <!--- If I look at what's loaded in firebug, the scripts load correctly -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site_media/css/gold/gold.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/js/jscal2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/js/en.js"></script>


<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="" id="edit_activity_form">
  <table>
   <tr><th>Date:</th>

       <td> <input type="text" id="id_activity_date" name="activity_date"> 
       <!-- When I click this button.  The calendar does not appear.  Instead I get a page refresh. -->
       <button id="calendar-trigger">...</button>

       <script type="text/javascript">
          Calendar.setup({
              trigger    : "calendar-trigger",
              inputField : "id_activity_date",
              onSelect   : function() { this.hide() }
          });
       </script></td>
   </td>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" onclick="send_activity_form();return false;" value="save" id="activity_save">
</form>
```

Comment: FYI I don't think this has anything to do with Django

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the function `send_activity_form()` defined anywhere.

Your onclick may be calling a nonexistent function.